# Python invalid syntax json.dumps

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am using the next script, and the output is: invalid syntax.

```
print json.dumps(data._json, indent=4)
```

Python 3.7.12

Comment: Aw, man, `print()` has been a function for all of Python 3. It was a statement in Python 2. Which tutorial are you following? I suggest finding a newer one.

Comment: It should be instead: `print(json.dumps(data._json, indent=4))`